# Microsoft Outlook freeze for users on terminal server - Exchange 2013 in-house

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, terminal-server

This has been ongoing for about six months.  Microsoft Support is also clueless.

Periodically (aprox. twice a day [two different users]), Outlook will freeze on a customer's terminal server session, forcing them to force close and start it back up.  There is only one symptom that is common between every occurance - CPU usage is stuck at 6%.  What's interesting is, the TS had Office 2010 installed, and this happened only to about five users out of the total 45.  We tried an upgrade to Office 2013, and now those five users don't experience this problem, but five *different* users do.

We have about 45 users on a Server 2008 R2 terminal server assigned with 52GB of RAM and 8 CPU cores on a Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V Host (2x Intel Xeon E5-2640).

Outlook is connected to the on-premise Exchange 2013 server - same host, but VM is Server 2012 R2 and has 18GB of RAM assigned with 8 CPU.

This has persisted across two AD domains, three terminal server rebuilds, and two Exchange server installations with new databases per instance.  I've rebuilt the Exchange DB, created new DBs, tried to repair mailboxes, etc.  Exchange is at the latest CU.

Event logs show nothing in either the Exchange Server or on the Terminal Server in regards to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a problem to go over two different AD domains would suggest there is something common between them both. Any third party tools installed? Same AV software for example? Most problems like this are usually caused by third party interference.

Did you remove the old versions of Office? I don't like upgrades of anything. Remove and replace is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the Outlook .ost file was on a network share. The network share was stable and so on but Outlook would randomly seize up on user computers. I suspected burst traffic would periodically cause the connect to fail and cause corruption of the file.

I moved the .ost back to the users device and end of issue. Perhaps not practical on a larger network but it worked for the 20 or so users on the small network that was experiencing the problem.